# Remote validation method never called

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC 4 form. Depending upon which country the user chose, a different regex validation has to be applied on the postalcode field. Essentially the regex pattern is set dynamically based upon another control's value. Remote validation attribute on the field where the regex has to be applied in the model class appears to be a good candidate for this need. The following is my code where Remote attribute is used on the postalcode field and the method to be called in my controller. I made sure that the case and name matches to the parameters of the method. Somehow the Remote validation never calls this method.

Model

```
[Display(Name = "Postal", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Interface.IAddress), Order = 0)]
[Remote("ValidatePostalCode", "NewCustomer", AdditionalFields = "CountryCode")]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult ValidatePostalCode(string PostalCode, string CountryCode)
{
    string ukValidation = @"^[A-Za-z]{1,2}[\d]{1,2}([A-Za-z])?\s?[\d][A-Za-z]{2}$";
    string usValidation = @"^\d{5}(-?\d{4})?$";
    if (CountryCode.Equals("US") || CountryCode.Equals("UK"))
    {
        if (CountryCode.Equals("US"))
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(usValidation);
            if (regex.IsMatch(PostalCode))
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Postal Code is in wrong format.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else if (CountryCode.Equals("UK"))
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(ukValidation);
            if (regex.IsMatch(PostalCode))
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("Postal Code is in wrong format.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
        }
    }     
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole validation controller and the model you apply to it? Right now, it seems that you have everything in one class

Comment: The first part of the code, where it shows the attributes for the PostalCode property, is in the model class. The second part of the code which has the code under ValidatePostalCode, is in my controller.

Comment: Are you sure you have the action "ValidatePostalCode" in NewCustomerController? I usually have a Validation controller in its own controller. ...make sure that the action exists in the specified controller

Comment: I moved the ValidatePostalCode method to a separate controller. Still it is not being called.

Comment: Have you really put a break point and that the method was not called?

Comment: Yes. It calls fine to the Save method in the controller which is called during the form post. The form is a popup form. I don't know whether that is causing the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80699/discussion-between-drifter-and-dan-hunex).

Comment: Show your view. You mentioned a popup - is that being loaded dynamically and if so are you reparsing the validator?